# Redirect action results error in laravel 4

Tags: laravel, laravel-4

I try to redirect all 404 errors by using redirect action.
In routes file I add these lines

```
App::missing(function($exception) {
        Redirect::action('LoginController@getError');
    });
```

and in LoginController I have the action getError
But it results an error

```
Error in exception handler: Route [LoginController@getError] not defined. in
D:\xampp\htdocs\mysite\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Routing\UrlGenerator.
php:209
```

But I have no problem in these line

```
App::missing(function($exception) {
        return Response::view('pages.error', array(), 404);
    });
```

Please help

Comment: Do you have a restful controller or not? Can you update the question with your LoginController?

Comment: @Andreo Vieira thanks for the reply . Now I got the point

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your second aproach you just render a view but in the first one you try to refer to a non existent route. Try defining it first, it should work. Remember to `composer dump-autoload` after you change routes.php

```
Route::get('pathwhatever/error', array('as'=>'error', 'uses' => 'LoginController@getError'));
App::missing(function($exception) {
            Redirect::action('LoginController@getError');
        });
```